# Render page content within a template?

Tags: magento2, theme

This seems like a basic request but I can't find it in the documentation. I'm using a from-scratch template(.phtml) and need to pull the CMS content onto the page. So how do I show the "content" field within my custom template?

Comment: cms block content or cms page content?

Comment: CMS Page Content

Comment: why you need cms page in phtml? you can directly call cms page on front using url

Comment: @PrashantValanda The .phtml file is the template for the CMS page, so it needs its own content.